# Laravel - Change Password issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I currently have a feature within my laravel application where a admin can create a new user account by filling in specific fields when you create the user it defaults the password value to `password` and is stored in the DB as a hash.

I've added a vue component for the password so it gives the admin the option to change to a custom password on creation.

My issue is when i want to add a custom password then click submit on creation of the user then try to login the custom password doesnt change but i can still login with the default password.

**Store Method**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $data['name'] = $data['first_name'] . ' ' . $data['last_name'];
    $data['password'] = bcrypt('password');
    $data['change_password'] = true;

    $user = User::create($data);

    session()->flash('success', 'User created successfully.');

    return back();
}
```

my guess is that the custom entered password isnt storing over the default password? can i get some help on this please.

Comment: I may be being blind here but at where is the form element / submission event to the server which updates the password? Is your vue component part of a larger html form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the password statically.

```
$data['password'] = bcrypt('password');
```

You need to change it to this.

```
$data['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
```

Comment: Okay now if i enter a custom password that changes fine thanks, but is there a way to set the password to a static value IF the admin doesnt choose to create a custom password themselves?

Comment: `bcrypt($request->password ? $request->password : 'password');`